# Ubuntu 14.04 Try to “sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa” failed

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ppa, ubuntu-tweak

I try to add ppa for install Ubuntu Tweak, but I can't do this. Terminal print: Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:tualatrix/ppa'. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct. Then how install Ubuntu Tweak?

```
>uname -a

Linux Inspiron-15-3552 3.13.0-161-generic #211-Ubuntu
 SMP Wed Oct 3 14:52:35 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


>lsb_release -crid

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty


>sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:tualatrix/ppa'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Comment: You should check your network connection and try again. The PPA you mentioned is alive and [provide packages for 14.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=trusty).

Comment: I turned off the firewall and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I turned off SpIDer Guard and SpIDer Gate that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your network connection settings and firewall and try again.

The PPA you mentioned ("The official Ubuntu Tweak stable repository") is [alive and provide packages for 14.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=trusty).

So you can install Ubuntu Tweak with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: I turned off SpIDer Guard and SpIDer Gate and it worked! Thank you!